# Using 2 Approvals in K2

Tags: k2, k2-smartforms

Quite a novice to using two Forms in K2 for Approval,Like an Originator and an approver, one sends the request, and the other Approves the request and sends to the second party who in turn verifies the information and upon update sends a notification to the Originator. I wanted to know how i can go about something like this Like where do i start? So far I have been able to have it linked to one of the Approvers , but in this case there are 2 of them like this chain

```
Originator -> First Reviewer (Approver) - > Second approver.
```

How do i go about something like this?

Answer (score 0):

there are different ways to accomplish this:

1. You might do it by adding 2 user tasks one after another - so that 2nd task is opened after 1st one is approved.
2. You might use single task with multiple recipient groups, configure task to require 2 responses, and then configure custom voting rule to achieve desired result.

Approach 1 would be easier to implement.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create two tasks one after another, the control goes to second task if the first one is approved. After the approval of second task you can add a email notification.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)